# Bitshift operators description in Java language specification

Tags: java, bit-shift, jls

At specified in JLS8 at [§JLS-15.19](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19)

> If the promoted type of the left-hand operand is int, **then only the five lowest-order bits of the right-hand operand are used as the shift distance**. It is as if the right-hand operand were subjected to a bitwise logical AND operator & (§15.22.1) with the mask value 0x1f (0b11111). The shift distance actually used is therefore always in the range 0 to 31, inclusive.

I am not clear about this statement in bold . An example is much appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's Java exploiting compiler optimisations from the C and C++ worlds. For a 32 bit `int`, using an bit-shift argument greater than or equal to 31 will set the resulting value to 0 for a positive `int`. (For a negative argument the behaviour in C and C++ on shifting is *implementation defined*).

Whereas in C and C++, actually using a value greater than 31 for a 32 bit `int` is in fact *undefined behaviour*, the Java bods have actually defined the behaviour specifically and simply perform the shift with an argument modulo 32 (which is what the majority of C and C++ compilers actually do). This method is mentioned explicitly in the JLS snippet you've quoted.

Extracting the lowest five order bits of a number is equivalent to taking that number modulo 32.

Comment: I am not clear about the statement in bold .I need an example if you can tell me with an example

Comment: I've added a final sentence. Is it still not clear?

Comment: Actually the last statement is what I wanted . I need to go back to masking ,I think. BTW Thanks

Comment: To me this epitomises why I think that *every* programmer should have a grounding in C. For me, C was the first living language to emerge from the primordial soup of language experimentation.

Comment: I actually am , but now It really required for me to go back there for more grounding.

Comment: "the Java bods have actually defined the behaviour specifically" <— What's a "bod" in this context?